# What is an Albert sensor?

Tags: network, ids, detection, government

Recent news articles have started to talk about government networks deploying "Albert sensors" (e.g., [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/04/26/us/florida-russia-hacking-election.html)).  What is an Albert sensor?  And how effective is it?

Going purely from context, it sounds like maybe an Albert sensor is a network tap for a network intrusion system, checking for known signatures of attacks (like Bro/Snort/Zeek). Maybe?  I'm speculating wildly.  Is it anything like that?  What's known about Albert sensors and how effective they are?

Answer (score 4):

Any chance it's this: https://www.cisecurity.org/services/albert/ ?

It says it's a [Suricata](https://suricata-ids.org/) based IDS (not clear to me what they add to plain Suricata, maybe this is a subscription to threat signature updates?).